# How can I prevent imported mailboxes from including event reminders?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange

In my role with my company we export and import a large number of mailboxes via powershell (New-mailboxexport/import).  We do this for archival and auditing purposes when people leave the company or there are legal concerns.  The issue is that whenever this is done, the exported mailbox includes all the event reminders, running outlook.exe /cleanreminders works, but only for the session that Outlook was opened in that way.  Is there a way to remove or strip the reminders when we import and export these pst files?  Alternatively, is there a way to permanently dismiss these reminders?

Comment: In case of legal concerns, couldn't the reminders be evidence?

Comment: The original mailbox is archived on our exchange server and in a forensic tool.  The legal concern is this case being that providing an exported mailbox is the viable alternative to granting full access to the original user's mailbox and diluting the audit trail.

Comment: There is a commercial product that provide a command line you can use to remove all reminders from any items in Exchange mailbox(es).